# PHP Foreach with two or more arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How to use Foreach on two or more php arrays?

My arrays are `$boardType, $hotelPrice and $hotelName`

Solution is to add $index in the other arrays as suffix

```
<?php foreach ($hotelName as $index => $name):?>
<div>
<p><?php echo $name;?></p>
<p><?php echo $hotelPrice[$index];?></p>
<p><?php echo $boardType[$index];?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach?>
```

Comment: you are asking about nested `foreach loop` for multiple arrays  or accessing multiple values `price`,`type`,`name` in a single array ?

Comment: So you want to loop through all 3 arrays an just print them?

Comment: @Rizier123 that is the solution found.

Comment: @em0tic0n If you found your own solution please don't put it in your question make an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just go through all 3 arrays with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) an print them in the structure you want)

```
<?php

    array_map(function($v1, $v2, $v3){
        echo "<div>";
            echo "<p>$v1</p>";
            echo "<p>$v2</p>";
            echo "<p>$v3</p>";
        echo "</div>";
    }, $boardType, $hotelPrice, $hotelName);

?>
```

Example input/output:

```
$boardType = [1,2,3];
$hotelPrice = [4,5,6];
$hotelName = [7,8,9];
```

```
<div>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>7</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>8</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>9</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If all arrays have exactly the same size you could use `each` to iterate through the other arrays at the same time as `$hotelName`:

```
<?php foreach ($hotelName as $index => $name):?>
    $price = each($hotelPrice);
    $boardType = each($boardType);
<div>
<p><?php echo $name;?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach?>
```

However, in that case it would probably being better to have just a single array containing all the data.

Comment: It was a little unclear question I think, so it was almost a trap. (Aus Berlin also, dann solltest du mich ja verstehen :D)

Comment: @Rizier123 Die array_map() Lösung ist super! +1 :)